# Converting a asp.net mvc webapi method to asp.net mvc method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a web api method in a web api controller as below which is working perfectly..

```
[Route("api/myquery")]
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage MyQuery([FromBody] string id)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
    {
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);      
}
```

I would like to use a similar one in my asp.net mvc controller..

I tried the following..

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyQuery(string id)
{      
    return this.Content("");
}
```

The data posted is sent from a same method in javascript.

```
$.ajax("/api/myquery", {
        data: JSON.stringify(tmp1),
        type: "post", contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (result) { alert("Saved Successfully") },
        error: function (result) { alert("Error Saving") }
    });
```

But, as MVC does not have a [FromBody] tag I'm unable to access the content being sent.. though the method is being called, id always shows null...

Comment: Assuming `tmp1` is `{ id: someValue }` then you need to specify the correct url -  `url: '/yourControllerName/myquery',` or better `url: '@Url.Action("myquery", "yourControllerName")',`

Comment: The method is being accessed meaning the cursor reaches inside the method on debug but id is always null

Comment: Are you sure the value of `tmp1` is `{ id: someValue }`?

Comment: the key was { id: someValue }  only tmp did not have id which is why id was coming null, tx..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
      [HttpPost]
      public ActionResult MyQuery(string id)
      {
          if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
          {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
          }
          return Json("message","text/json",JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);      
      }
```

and change your url in ajax post (replace api by your controller name: put "home" if you are under home controller for example)

```
$.ajax("home/myquery", {
    /*data: JSON.stringify(tmp1),*/
    data:  JSON.stringify({id:tmp1}),
    type: "post", contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (result) { alert("Saved Successfully") },
    error: function (result) { alert("Error Saving") }
    });
```